# Active and passive verb with different prepositions for same object - commas?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, commas, writing-style

I've got a sentence like this:

> A will impose B on and further be affected by C

The two verbs have nothing in common, they both just put A in some relation to C. As C is quite long I don't want to write two sentences.

Is this correct English? If yes, were do I put my commas?

Is there a nicer way to write this?

Comment: If *C* is quite long, it might be better to use two sentences rather than add complexity with commas (which set off the parenthetical phrase *and further be affected by*). Perhaps you could give real-world examples instead of *A, B* and *C*?

Comment: There are examples of constructions like this in the wild, but not all that many. Finding one from the 19th century (they seem more common nowadays) [From this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=2HIFAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA139&dq=%22was+surprised+by+and+%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=q_PfUoaWBaOzsATAyIHoCg&ved=0CFMQ6AEwBzgK#v=onepage&q=%22was%20surprised%20by%20and%20%22&f=false) *He believes that Le Breton … was surprised by, and yielded to a great temptation.*

Comment: But in that case B and C are the same thing so it make more sense.

Comment: If C is long, that is what pronouns were invented for. A will be affected by C. A will therefore impose B on them (or it).

Answer (score 2):

The sentence as you have written it is very unclear. Is A affected by C? Or is B affected by C? The traditional structure for this would be:

> A will impose B on, and further be affected by, C

A more elegant way of writing this would be:

> A will impose B on C and will further be affected by the latter/former.